# golang rate limit per minute

Tags: go, time, rate-limiting

How to rate limit 20 requests per minute?

```
import "golang.org/x/time/rate"

limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(1*time.Minute), 20)

for {
    limiter.Wait()
    //more code
}
```

This does not work. What that does is, it allows first 20 requests, then only allows 1 request per minute. What is expected is 20 requests on the first minute(Need not be evenly spread like 1 per 3 seconds) and then 20 more requests on the second minute. At any 1 minute interval, there cannot be more than 20 requests sent.

My solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72452542

Comment: `golang.org/x/time/rate` implements token bucket and works exactly like that. If it's not what you want - you need to find other package or implement it yourself.

Comment: @zerkms Is there any other package that can limit based on the specified duration, like 10 requests per minute, and it can allow 10 at any point of time in the minute burst or evenly spread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution

```
import (
        "sync"
        "time"
)

type Limiter interface {
        Wait()
}

type limiter struct {
        tick    time.Duration
        count   uint
        entries []time.Time
        index   uint
        mutex   sync.Mutex
}

func NewLimiter(tick time.Duration, count uint) Limiter {
        l := limiter{
                tick:  tick,
                count: count,
                index: 0,
        }
        l.entries = make([]time.Time, count)
        before := time.Now().Add(-2 * tick)
        for i, _ := range l.entries {
                l.entries[i] = before
        }
        return &l
}
func (l *limiter) Wait() {
        l.mutex.Lock()
        defer l.mutex.Unlock()
        last := &l.entries[l.index]
        next := last.Add(l.tick)
        now := time.Now()
        if now.Before(next) {
                time.Sleep(next.Sub(now))
        }
        *last = time.Now()
        l.index = l.index + 1
        if l.index == l.count {
                l.index = 0
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Set the rate you expect :

```
limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(1*time.Minute/20), 20)

for {
    limiter.Wait()
    //more code
}
```

playground: https://go.dev/play/p/ZpxpHj0vK7P

---

You seem to look for something that allows "bursts of up to 20, reset every minute". Here is a go at it :

```
type Limiter struct {
    maxCount int
    count    int
    ticker   *time.Ticker
    ch       chan struct{}
}

func (l *Limiter) run() {
    for {
        // if counter has reached 0: block until next tick
        if l.count <= 0 {
            <-l.ticker.C
            l.count = l.maxCount
        }

        // otherwise:
        // decrement 'count' each time a message is sent on channel,
        // reset 'count' to 'maxCount' when ticker says so
        select {
        case l.ch <- struct{}{}:
            l.count--

        case <-l.ticker.C:
            l.count = l.maxCount
        }
    }
}

func (l *Limiter) Wait() {
    <-l.ch
}

func NewLimiter(d time.Duration, count int) *Limiter {
    l := &Limiter{
        maxCount: count,
        count:    count,
        ticker:   time.NewTicker(d),
        ch:       make(chan struct{}),
    }
    go l.run()

    return l
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/5WiOJL5nqCy

Comment: What this does is sends 20 requests in a burst and then one request per 3 seconds. What I want it 20 requests per minute.

Comment: @balki: you will note that it does send 20 requests per minute ;) ok, you want bursts that reset every minute.

Comment: Say the first request was sent at 1:00:00, and then 19 was sent at 1:00:59 and 20 more at 1:01:01, There won't be any waiting as after the tick at 1:01:00, the count is reset. But if you look at the 1 minute time interval from 1:00:58 to 2:00:58, there are 39 requests sent in a minute. I initially went with this approach too.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `time.Tick` and `for-select` like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    max := 20

    limiter := time.Tick(1 * time.Minute)

    exit := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        count := 0
        exit2 := 0
        defer func() {
            exit <- struct{}{}
        }()
        for {
            select {
            case <-limiter:
                count = 0
                fmt.Println("exit2: ", exit2)
                if exit2 == 3 {
                    return
                }
                exit2++
            default:
                if count == max {
                    continue
                }
                fmt.Println("accepting request", count)
                count++
            }
        }
    }()

    <-exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    limiter := time.Tick(3 * time.Minute) //changed from 20 to 3 because i realized you wanted 20 requests per minute, not 1 request per 20 minutes

    for true {
        <-limiter
        fmt.Println(time.Now())
    }
}
```

I haven't actually tried with `20 * time.Minute` as the value, but I tried `200 * time.Milisecond` and it worked. Here was my response

```
2022-05-31 00:06:13.447108 -0600 MDT m=+0.200889915
2022-05-31 00:06:13.651373 -0600 MDT m=+0.405148283
2022-05-31 00:06:13.851522 -0600 MDT m=+0.605291066
2022-05-31 00:06:14.051481 -0600 MDT m=+0.805244205
2022-05-31 00:06:14.250144 -0600 MDT m=+1.003900790
2022-05-31 00:06:14.450952 -0600 MDT m=+1.204703429
2022-05-31 00:06:14.648365 -0600 MDT m=+1.402110595
2022-05-31 00:06:14.848223 -0600 MDT m=+1.601961982
2022-05-31 00:06:15.04909 -0600 MDT m=+1.802823232
2022-05-31 00:06:15.250164 -0600 MDT m=+2.003891217
```